# Don't quite understand what the address of & operator is doing in this struct and how its able to access the other member variables

Tags: c++, struct

I'm starting to get grips with c++ and I thought I would learn about creating vectors and doing manipulations on them and in doing so I would get to grips with pointers and references.
Maybe I've been looking at it too long but I'm not quite sure what is going on the with the section of code related to the return statement with the book I'm following along has given me, more specifically the `return ((&x)[i]);` part.
Listed below:

```
float& operator [](int i)
{
    return ((&x)[i]);
}
```

My understanding is that `&` - address operator would give you the address of a particular variable. Now if I remember correctly pointers and arrays go hand in hand, so when you get a reference to the `x` variable like so `(&x)[i]` you are able to access the next element using an offset operator but I didn't know you could do this with structs.

Am I on the right track or have I lost it?

Using the following links to help me:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

```cpp
struct Vector3D
{
    float       x, y, z;

    Vector3D() = default;

    Vector3D(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }

    float& operator [](int i)
    {
        return ((&x)[i]);
    }

    const float& operator [](int i) const
    {

        return ((&x)[i]);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Vector3D vec = Vector3D(1,2,3);
    auto test = vec[1];
    std::cout << test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the value printed here would be 2 but I don't quite get the `&x` reference being able to access the struct member values?

Comment: throw the tutorial away and instead use a book from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you want to learn C++.  The code has  **horrible** practices in it and should not be used.

Comment: Ahhh man, I actually had the topic down or the operational use of it until this book confused me, so what is it even doing? Was I at least along the lines of understanding it.

Comment: `but I didn't know you could do this with structs.` You can't. This is undefined behavior. It may work for logical reasons but the code is invalid. **DO NOT** use this or learn from anybody that suggests this.

Comment: `&x` is not a reference. It is a pointer to x.  Thus, `(&x)[1]` is the glvalue, y since y is placed in the struct right after x.  Don't write code like that though. It's shown that way to, hopefully, show how C++ works. Any instruction or book that shows this sort of thing should take pains to say it is horrible coding style.

Comment: Well that's going in the bin then, cheers

Comment: Just for reference, the simple way to write this in C++ (11 and up) is `using Vector3D = std::array<float, 3>;`. Really, it saves so much effort ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What

```
return ((&x)[i]);
```

does is take the address of `x`, and then using `[i]`, it gets the object at the offset of `i` from `x`.  Basically, you are pretending you have an array of `int`'s, instead of 3 seperate `int`'s, with `x` being the first element of the array.

This is undefined behavior for a couple of reason though.  First, you cannot access an element that is out of bounds for the array.  An object can be considered an array of one so `(&variable)[0]` is legal, as it is just `variable` (ignoring that `&` could be overloaded).  So any index besides `0` is UB.  Secondly, the compiler is allowed to put padding between member variables of a class.  This means that you can't know, without asserting the class is the size you expect, that `y` and `z` are adjacent to `x` in memory.

The correct way to write the function would be use use a switch statement like

```
float& operator [](int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        case 2: return z;
        default: // throw an exception or return one of the members or do something else to indicate an error
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that makes much more bloody sense, in fact I wondered why it was written the way it was in the first place, cheers. Im going to pick up one of the recommended books as a good reference

Comment: Leaving out the `default` and letting UB happen in case of out-of-bound access lets clang optimize all of this to a lovely [`lea     eax, [rdi + 1]; ret`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fKgRm3) :)

Comment: Whether subsequent data members of the same type are allocated sequentially in a struct appears to be implementation defined (see 12.2.17), not UB. So, not portable. However, there remains accessing beyond the type bounds which is UB since it plays havoc with compiler optimization.

Comment: @gman Depends on what the OP wants.  If they want to access the members with names, then this is the way to do it.  If they only want to access with an array syntax, then using an array would be better.

Comment: @gman Well, if you want to access them like `foo.x`, you have to have a member variable or use references.  Using references will make the class size explode so it should be avoided.  If the OP is okay accessing it like `foo.x()` then you could use an array.

Comment: Doh! My C++ is rusty. Had a brainfart and forgot C++ doesn't have language level getters and setters.